# Setting Page Height using wxpython HtmlEasyPrinting class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I had developed a program in python 2.7 wxpython for a gold merchant to add entries of clients and print these reports one by one using a dotmatrix printer. But the issue is page size of this printer is that of an envelope. So to correctly print, i must be able to set page size while using htmleasyprinting.

class Printer(HtmlEasyPrinting):
    def **init**(self):
        HtmlEasyPrinting.**init**(self)

```
def GetHtmlText(self,text):
    "Simple conversion of text.  Use a more powerful version"
    html_text = text.replace('\n\n','<P>')
    html_text = text.replace('\n', '<BR>')

    return html_text

def Print(self, text, doc_name):
    self.SetHeader(doc_name)
    self.PrintText(self.GetHtmlText(text),doc_name)

def PreviewText(self, text, doc_name):
    self.SetHeader(doc_name)
    HtmlEasyPrinting.PreviewText(self, text)
```

When i print using the above code, instead of one page, three pages are output by the printer since the actual page is only the height of envelope.

I read the htmleasyprinter class and there are no methods to set the page size. Is there any other alternative to do this. Client has given an ultimatum.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're fired by now but I hope you aren't. Anyway, I'm currently working with that class and maybe I can help anyone with the same problem. `HtmlEasyPrinting` has a parameter called `PrintData` which is the one who has the `PaperSize`.

So, something like this will work:

```
HtmlEasyPrintingObj.GetPageSetupData().SetPaperSize((110,220))
```

The size is calculated in milimeters.